# Ruby - Array.length returning character count instead of element count

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.0 for a Rails project and am having some issues obtaining the element length of an array in the console.

First example

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > search = "test"
 => "test" 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > search.split
 => ["test"] 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > search.length
 => 4
```

Second example

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > search = "testOne, TestTwo"
 => "testOne, TestTwo" 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > search.split(/[\s,]+/)
 => ["testOne", "TestTwo"] 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > search.length
 => 16
```

How do I return the element count instead of the character count?

Comment: `search.split.length => 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're not assigning your split array that's why you're seeing the discrepancy.
What you're actually doing is defining a string `search` and then trying to manipulate that same string.

Try this

```
testArray = search.split
testArray.size
>> 1
```

Comment: Np, mate! :) Merry Giftgiving Day!

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are getting the length of the `"test"` string, not of the `["test"]` array. You should assign it to a variable first.

i.e.:

```
search = "test"       # => "test"
array = search.split  # => ["test"]
array.length          # => 1
```